# connect 4 java issues: How do I do this?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d-games

I am a noob to java, as well as programming, and I am having large difficulties picturing how to actually execute each method in order to create the Connect Four game. There are 4 methods, main, printBoard, checkWinner, and playerMove. I may add more methods if necessary. I am overwhelmed and need a ton of guidance. how to approach each method? Sorry if this is a mammoth question, I am throughly confused.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConnectFour{

```
// We will represent the game board using a 2 dimensional integer array.
// Each entry of the array will contain a 0, 1, or -1.
// A 0 entry in the array represents an empty slot. 
// A 1 entry represents Player 1's piece.
// A -1 entry represents Player 2's piece.
// Since most methods will need to access this board, we have decided to
// make it a global class variable.
```

import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConnectFour{

```
public static int[][] board = new int[6][7]; 

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // initializing board
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){ 
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }

    }

    // WRITE CODE HERE
    if (j < 7 && j >= 0) 
        f[i][j] =".";
    else f[i][j] = " ";

    return board;

}
```

}

```
// This method prints the board on the screen. 
// To represent Player 1's pieces, print 'X'.
// To represent Player 2's pieces, print 'O'.
// To represent an empty slot, print '.'.
public static void printBoard(){

    // WRITE CODE HERE
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)

    {

        for (int j = 0;j < 7; j++)

        {

            System.out.print(f[i][j]);

        }

        System.out.println();

    }

}



// This method scans the current board and checks if there is a winner.
// The method should return 1 if Player 1 has connected 4 pieces.
// It should return -1 if Player 2 has connected 4 pieces.
// It should return 0 if no player has connected 4 pieces.
public static int checkWinner(){

    // WRITE CODE HERE


return;}


// This method implements a player's move and updates the board accordingly.
// The method has two integer inputs. 
// The first input indicates the player (1 for Player 1, -1 for Player 2).
// The second input indicates the column number that the player has
// chosen to play.
// If the column number is out of range or the column is currently full,
// the method should return false.
// Otherwise, the board should be updated and the method should return true.

public static boolean playerMove(int player, int columnNum){

    // WRITE CODE HERE


}
```

}

Comment: "I am overwhelmed and need a ton of guidance." -- sorry, but that's not what this website is for (or good at). You need to talk to your teacher/tutor/peers for help.

Comment: You're kind of a long way off having a complete solution for this.  I recommend you start with something easier, and have another go at this when you're more comfortable with Java.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how your program should work, logically. I would personally put your board in a separate class, but it's not too important, especially since the program is pretty small. This isn't really as much as a code problem as much as a logic one, so we'll walk through how the game works.

First off, what does each function do? We have checkWinner(), playerMove(), and printBoard(). So we'll have a loop until the game ends, which should be controlled by checkWinner(), like so

```
while !checkWinner
```

So the game will loop until a winner is found, and any code executed after the while loop is end game code. Inside our while loop should go all of code executed every frame while there is no winner, since that is how our while loop is setup now. So let's think about what should execute every frame of your game.
printBoard()? Yeah, probably, since we want to update the display every frame right?

playerMove()? Yeah, since if the game hasn't ended, we want the players to execute a move. However, you need to make sure that the code is functional for switching between players. If you do that, the basic game loop should be finished. Here's some psuedocode for that

```
//setup board here
while !checkWinner
    printBoard
    playerMove
//since checkwinner did not return 0, a player won. so we put in endgame code here
```

The main issue here is thinking out how your program should work, logically. So plan out which functions do what, and try to write it out.
Hope that helps.